# How to explicitly launch the stock launcher from my activity?

Tags: android, android-launcher

Platform: ASUS Nexus 7, running JellyBean

---

I've created a kiosk application by making it the default HOME / LAUNCHER intent. I need to be able to get out of it, to the stock android launcher, via a secret code for service and maintenance.

I've searched all over, and can't find a good, succinct answer. The best I've come up with is to create an intent chooser (`Intent.createChooser(Intent i, String title)`) and choose between my launcher and the stock launcher. This is okay, but really a workaround.

I've tried:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

try {
    Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.launcher");
    if (i != null)
        this.startActivity(i);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { }
```

and I get null for the intent every time. Yet, the stock launcher shows a package of "com.android.launcher" on my tablet. Clearly I'm getting something totally wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Document that they need to run your app manually once out of the launcher before setting it up as the home screen.

Step #2: On that first run, use `resolveActivity()` to find out what the default home screen is, and hold onto the relevant pieces of information from the `ResovleInfo` (e.g., the component name) in some persistent data store.

Step #3: Use that data to bring up the default home screen as needed from whatever back door you have in your kiosk app.